# Receiving undefined reference error c++ inheritance/polymorphism

Tags: c++

I am learning how to program in c++ and I am making an attempt at polymorphism. When I compile these cpp files into object files I do not receive any errors. When I attempt to make an executable, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccsiYtzo.o: In function `expression::expression()':
constant.cpp:(.text._ZN10expressionC2Ev[_ZN10expressionC5Ev]+0x30): undefined reference to `vtable for expression'
/tmp/ccsiYtzo.o:(.rodata+0x24): undefined reference to `typeinfo for expression'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using the following command to compile:

```
g++ constant.cpp main.cpp -o expression
```

My understanding with this error message is that the constructor expression must be defined, but I believe I have defined it. Additionally, I have tried to exclude declaring/defining expression() because the default constructor should work; however, it results in the same error. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

expression.h

```
class expression{
public:
    expression(){}
    int virtual eval();
    char virtual * infix();
    char virtual * postfix();
};

class constant : public expression{
public:
    constant(int);
    int eval();
    char * infix();
    char * postfix();
private:
    int constantInt;
};
```

constant.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

constant::constant(int i){
        constantInt = i;

}

int constant::eval(){
    return constantInt;
}

char * constant::infix(){
    char *retval = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    sprintf(retval, "%d", constantInt);
    return retval;
}

char * constant::postfix(){
    return infix();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "expression.h"

using namespace std;
int main(){

    expression *test = new constant(5);

    cout << test -> eval();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is it perhaps your intention to make the virtual functions in class expression pure? Also virtual destructor is needed.

Comment: Please, make `infix` (and `postfix`) return a `std::string`.  You will save yourself many, *many* hours of painful debugging like this.  Any time you write a naked `new`, you are almost certainly doing it wrong.

Comment: Add `= 0` next to each `virtual` function declaration in the base class. Alternatively, you can add `{return some_default_value;}` or something, but I'm assuming that this is not your purpose.

Comment: *typeinfo for `expression`* would likely appear when you compile expression.cpp. Where is that file?

Comment: Then you write:  `std::unique_ptr<expression> = std::make_unique<constant>(5);` - viola, no more memory leaks.  (Also, all of those methods should be `const`.  )

Comment: `char *retval = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));` is only allocating space for 1 character, which is useless for c-strings since that can only include the null terminator. Like the others say use `std::string`.

Comment: Did you forget include guards for `expression.h`?

Comment: @MartinBonner If only I could use string :P Homework assignment

Comment: Ug.  That's crap.  I'd still write a small RAII class to handle string memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should insert [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h files.

Your problem is that you are declaring your `class expression` with with virtual keyword, but not making an abstract (with the end with `= 0`). This means that the compiles expect to see a definition of it.

To solve your problem, or add a definition to your class:

```
class expression{
public:
    expression(){}
    virtual ~expression() {}
    int virtual eval() {}
    char virtual * infix() {}
    char virtual * postfix() {}
};
```

Or make it abstract:

```
class expression{
public:
    expression(){}
    virtual ~expression() {};
    int virtual eval() = 0;
    char virtual * infix() = 0;
    char virtual * postfix() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I really like your second solution to make it abstract, the only issue is I then get errors with my unary operator class that has a reference to another expression. I am not sure how to resolve this.

The first solution worked perfectly, I see where I wasn't creating the definitions now. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe Those problems are not in OP. So, I cant help.

Comment: @JohnDoe Use the pure virtual approach, then ask *another* question about the unary operator class.

Comment: Thanks I followed your advice @MartinBonner and created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021170/receiving-compilation-errors-when-trying-to-reference-an-abstract-object-in-chil

Answer (score 1):

By using the keyword “virtual,” in your base class ‘expression’, you are setting up those functions to be overridden by a derived class. However, this alone doesn’t mean that it will ALWAYS be overridden. The linker will still enforce that the base class has implementations for symbols (functions) that are marked virtual for cases where you make an object of that type.

However in your case it looks like you intended to make an abstract base class, ie one that isn’t supposed to have concrete instances. To fix in this case, you decorate your abstract functions with a trailing ‘ = 0; ‘ . This marks them as “pure virtual.” Then not only do they not require an implementation in the base class, the compiler will error if you attempt to define one.