# Receiving compilation errors when trying to reference an abstract object in child class

Tags: c++

I am attempting to understand a pure virtual approach to creating a polymorphic solution in c++. I currently have 3 classes, expression (abstract), constant (child of expression), and unop (child of expression). The class unop holds a reference to another expression (it could hold a unop, constant, or in the future binop). When I attempt to compile unop.cpp I get the following error:

```
unop.cpp:6:20: error: ‘expression’ is not a type
 unop::unop(char c, expression *e){
                    ^
unop.cpp:6:1: error: prototype for ‘unop::unop(char, int*)’ does not match any in class ‘unop’
 unop::unop(char c, expression *e){
 ^
In file included from unop.cpp:2:0:
expression.h:21:7: error: candidates are: unop::unop(const unop&)
 class unop: public expression{
       ^
expression.h:23:2: error:                 unop::unop(char, expression*)
  unop(char, expression*);
  ^
expression.h:29:14: error: ‘expression* unop::expression’ is private
  expression *expression;
              ^
unop.cpp:6:20: error: within this context
 unop::unop(char c, expression *e){
```

My code is as follows:

expression.h

```
class expression{
public:
    expression(){}
    virtual ~expression() {}
    int virtual eval() = 0;

    char virtual * infix() = 0;
    char virtual * postfix() = 0;
};

class constant : public expression{
public:
    constant(int);
    int eval();
    char * infix();
    char * postfix();
private:
    int constantInt;
};

class unop : public expression{
public:
    unop(char, expression*);
    int eval();
    char * infix();
    char * postfix();
private:
    char operatorChar;
    expression *expression;
};
```

constant.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

constant::constant(int i){
        constantInt = i;

}

int constant::eval(){
    return constantInt;
}

char * constant::infix(){
    char *retval = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(retval, "%d", constantInt);
    return retval;
}

char * constant::postfix(){
    return infix();
}
```

unop.cpp

```
#include "expression.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unop::unop(char c, expression *e){
        operatorChar = c;
        expression = e;
}

int unop::eval(){
    return 0;
}

char * unop::infix(){
    return NULL;
}

char * constant::postfix(){
    return NULL;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "expression.h"

using namespace std;
int main(){

    expression *test = new constant(5);

    cout << test -> eval();

    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am starting to slowly understand what is going on, but I find this quite a bit more convoluted than other languages I have worked with.

Comment: It's not as simple as `#include "unop.h"` rather than `"expression.h"` at the top of `unop.cpp` is it?  Or is that a typo when creating the question.

Comment: Error here redefinition: `expression *expression;` in `class unop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
class unop : public expression{
public:
    unop(char, expression*);
    int eval();
    char * infix();
    char * postfix();
private:
    char operatorChar;
    expression *expression; // <<<HERE
};
```

When you write:

```
unop::unop(char c, expression *e)
```

`expression` gets looked up in the context of `unop`, and finds the local member variable; *not* the base class.

You need to change the name of the member : `expr` perhaps?

**Edit**: In addition, as [Raindrop7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2874856/raindrop7) points out, `unop.cpp` defines another (different) copy of `constant::postfix` rather than defining `unop::postfix`.  Looks like a copy-paste error!

Comment: In `unop.cpp` The OP doesn't override `char* postfix` But writes: `char * constant::postfix()`. Where he must use: `char * unop::postfix()`

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors:

```
expression *pExpression;
```

So wherever you find `expression =` change it to `pExpression =`.

You cannot use a type as an identifier like:

```
int int = 0; // error
```

So change it to something else:

```
 expression* pExpression; // for example
```

Also you have link-time error: You must implement all the pure virtual methods in derived classes to be able to instantiate the derived ones:

I think you meant:

```
char * unop::postfix(){ // not char * constant::postfix in Unop.cpp
    return NULL;
}
```